# How to merge PDF with RTF in JAVA?

Tags: java, merge, itext

I have 2 Documents in my File System. One PDF file another one is RTF file I want to merge those 2 documents and create a single PDF which should contain the data for both RTF and PDF using JAVA.

Comment: Your question is vague. It's involved too many concepts, file manipulation , database , pdf converting. Don't think to get any answer with such approach.

Comment: Modified the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Split your task into multiple, easy to do subtasks. Start with parsing the RTF, read the RTF, then learn how to modify a PDF, add the parsed RTF content, write the new PDF. There is no library that will fix all you want in one line. You have to put in the effort yourselves.

Comment: Convert your RTF into a PDF and then use itext to concatenate both PDFs. Itext back in the days supported RTF conversion (Version 2.1.7) but not anymore. The PDF concatenations is quite easy with iText but the conversion from RTF to PDF is quite a task...